# Fill content 100% width for smaller resolution/mobile

Tags: css, html, mobile, width

Hi I currently am working on a site where it's set to imitate 100% width of the browser. However on mobile devices the content does not take up the entire width of the browser nor on smaller resolutions. I've tried @media-screen inputs for mind width for all different devices and it doesn't seem to work.

```
body, html {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background:url(images/bg.jpg);
}
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, acronym, address, big, cite, code, del, dfn, em, font, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp, small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, b, u, i, center, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td {
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after, q:before, q:after {
    content: none;
}
:focus {
    outline: 0;
}
del {
    text-decoration: line-through;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
.fl {
    float: left;
}
.fr {
    float: right;
}
.ac {
    text-align: center;
}
.ar {
    text-align: right;
}
.col-full:after {
    content:".";
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
}
h1 {
    font-size: 2em;
}
h2 {
    font-size: 1.8em;
}
h3 {
    font-size: 1.6em;
}
h4 {
    font-size: 1.2em;
}
h5 {
    font-size: 1em;
}
h6 {
    font-size: .8em;
}
p {
    margin: 0;
}
hr {
    background-color: #e6e6e6;
    border: 0;
    height: 1px;
}
input, textarea {
    padding: 5px;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-radius: 3px;
    color: #222;
}
a {
    color: #222;
    text-decoration: none;
}
h1 a:link, h1 a:visited, h2 a:link, h2 a:visited, h3 a:link, h3 a:visited h4 a:link, h4 a:visited, h5 a:link, h5 a:visited, h6 a:link, h6 a:visited h1 a:hover, h2 a:hover, h3 a:hover, h4 a:hover, h5 a:hover, h6 a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}
#main {
    width: 100%;
}
#main.col-full, .layout-full #main, .col-full, #main.fullwidth {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 25px 50px;
}
.nav {
    list-style: none;
    font: normal 3em Futura, sans-serif;
    color: #222;
}
.nav a {
    color:#222;
    line-height:2.75em;
    padding-left:25px;
}
.nav ul li {
    float: left;
}
.nav a:hover {
    color: #029b9d;
}
.toggleBtn {
    display : block;
    cursor : pointer;
    margin:0;
}
.toggleBtn:hover {
    color : #dd2591;
    transition : all 0.5s ease;
}
.below {
    background : #f5f5f5;
    width : 100% position : relative;
    height : 100%;
    overflow : hidden;
    opacity : 0.949999988079071044921875
}
#header {
    width:100%;
    position: relative;
}
.logo {
    float: left;
    width:300px;
    height:110px;
    background:url(images/logo.png);
}
#footer-container {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 25px 50px;
    font: normal 1em Futura, sans-serif;
}
.advent {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    height: 350px;
    width: 610px;
    background:#222;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
    transition: all 1s ease;
}
.one {
    background:url(images/1.jpg);
}





<div class="col-full"></div>
<div id="header" class="col-full">
<div class="clear"></div>
<div class="logo"></div>
<div class="nav">
<ul>
<li><a class="toggleBtn">home</li></a>
<li><a class="toggleBtn">collaborate</a></li>   
<li><a class="toggleBtn">connect</a></li>   
</ul>                   
</div>
<div class="below">
                                <h2>Camera/Sound</h2>

                                <p><strong>Responsibilites at
                                WG206?</strong><br />
                                I direct and coordinate WG206 Episodes.<br />
                                <br />
                                <strong>Favorite WG206 moment?</strong> CHS
                                2012 Youth Camp<br />
                                <br />
                                <strong>Future plans?</strong><br />
                                Keep making awesome episodes.</p>

                                <div class="smc">
                                    <a class="fb" href="#"></a> <a class="tw"
                                    href="#"></a>
                                </div>
</div>
<!-- /#header --></div>
<div id="main" class="col-full">
<div class="advent one"></div>
<div class="advent one"></div>
<div class="advent one "></div>
<div class="advent one"></div>
<div class="advent one"></div>
<div class="advent one"></div>
<div class="advent one"></div>
<div class="advent one"></div>
<div class="advent one"></div>
<!-- /#main -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: why reinvent the wheel when you can get a free pre-built responsive framework like: http://foundation.zurb.com/, http://www.amazium.co.uk/ or http://getbootstrap.com/ - just customise one of them.

Comment: you have margin on your containers: `margin: 25px 50px;` so they won't take up full width. Also you don't actually close your main div

Answer (score 5):

I am currently dabbling in responsive css and when I was doing my @media queries they didn't work until I added:

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">` in between the `<head>` tags.

Also make sure it's @media screen not @media-screen

Example:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px)  
{         
     .header .user-bar {
         display:none;
     }
}
```